# Gnuplot - start date and time + incremented minutes

Tags: date, time, format, gnuplot, increment

I have a question about Gnuplot - my measurement device records the start date and time (ex. 15.09.2020 15:09:00 format can be changed), every measurement is done after every 60 minutes. I do not know the ending time. How should I do the x-axis, so that axis tics are "day.month" ?

Comment: I understand that the first line contains a date/time stamp and all further lines do not contain a timestamp but are taken 1 hour after the previous one, correct? Please clarify and show a few lines of example data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep in mind, in gnuplot time and date is handled as seconds from January, 1st 1970 00:00:00.
In gnuplot console check `help strptime`, `help format`. Try the following:

**Code:**

```
### convert relative time into absolute time
reset session

$Data <<EOD
minutes;temperature
0;12.8829
60;4.5346
120;4.5417
180;4.5454
240;4.5394
1440;2.22
2880;1.11
10000;0.00
EOD

set datafile separator ";"
Startdate = strptime("%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S","15.09.2020 15:09:00")
myTime(col) = Startdate + column(col)*60

set format x "%d.%m." timedate

plot $Data u (myTime(1)):2 w lp pt 7
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I know, that temperature logger started:
15.09.2020 15:09:00

The datafile.csv contains:

```
minutes;temperature
0;12.8829
60;4.5346
120;4.5417
180;4.5454
240;4.5394
```